# How do I get recent entries from zinnia?

Tags: django, zinnia

I want to make a div that shows the most recent entries and their content but I don't see anywhere in the documentation on how to do this, I've tried the template tags but they only show the name of the entry and not the content? Could some one show me what I'm suppose to do?

Comment: Post your views.py, forms.py and models.py

Comment: Which one, the zinnia app or my own? I haven't done anything like that in my own app because I don't know where to start.